# Python 3 class not printing from function

Tags: python

So i'm trying to wrap my head around the `__init__` and functions. I am following the book, "Learn Python 3 the hard way" and I'm struggling to work out why my code won't print from a function but prints just fine from within the class.

from the code below:

```
class FirstScene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print("printing scene 1")

class SecondScene(object):
    pass

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        "scene_one": FirstScene(),
        "scene_two": SecondScene()
    }

    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene

game_start = Map("scene_one")
```

When I run this. I don't get any output, but when I print directly from the class like this:

```
class FirstScene(object):
    print("printing scene 1")
```

It works. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `enter` method won't be executed unless you actually call it.

Comment: This question is basically _"Why aren't functions executed if I don't call them?"_ Sounds a little silly, doesn't it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Where would I call the function from? the `game_start = Map("scene_one")`?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49732897/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a change to your code that prints:

```
class FirstScene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print("printing scene 1")

class SecondScene(object):
    pass

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        "scene_one": FirstScene(),
        "scene_two": SecondScene()
    }

    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.scene = self.scenes[scene]   ##### 1. Access the scene instance
        self.scene.enter()                ##### 2. Tell it to print

game_start = Map("scene_one")
```

In `Map.__init__`, `scene` is the string `"scene_one"`  At #1 above, you need to actually use the `scenes` dictionary that you created to get the `FirstScene()` or `SecondScene()` instance.

Once you have an instance, at #2 above, you call the `enter()` method to cause whatever `enter()` does to happen.  In this case, that is printing `printing scene 1`.

Comment: this is great! Thank you. Easy to understand now. How could I then go to SecondScene after FirstScene has run its code? i tried a `return "SecondScene"` and printing some text in there. but it printed off SecondScene then FirstScene

Comment: @marksus1 Glad to be able to help!  As the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) will tell you, a thank you on SO is usually an upvote (the arrow left of the question) - you can upvote any answer.  The answer that best solves your particular problem gets a checkmark.  For further issues, you will probably get better help if you ask a separate question.  As with this question, show the code you've tried.  Code is too difficult to read in one of these comment boxes :) .  (I'm guessing you may be looking for `self.scenes["scene_two"].enter()`, but that's just a guess.)

Answer (score 1):

You never call the `enter()` method of `FirstScene` object, this is why nothing is printed.

Change `self.scene = scene` by `self.scene = Map.scenes[scene]` to get the actual object, then call its `enter` method (but be warned that this method is not defined for `SecondScene` objects!).

Another possibility is to rename `enter` of `FirstScene` to `__init__`, so the print will be made upon instanciation. In that case, you have to decide whether you want to instanciate your objects when defining `Map.scenes` as you're currently doing, or in the `__init__` method of `Map`, e.g., using `self.scene = Map.scenes[scene]()`. In that case, you have to change the way you defined your dictionary on `Map`:

```
scenes = {
    "scene_one": FirstScene,
    "scene_two": SecondScene,
}
```

A more elegant way to do it:

```
class FirstScene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("printing scene 1")

class SecondScene(object):
    pass

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene()

game_start = Map(FirstScene)
```

i.e., you pass to the `__init__` method of `Map` the class that has to be instanciated upon initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__()` is short for "initialize" and is the python way of dealing with something called *Constructors* in object oriented programming.

I think it's best to use examples. Let's say you're creating a program called dog simulator.

```
# Notice that animals are a CLASS of objects.
class Animal:
        # Before we do anything, we have to create an instance of an object.
        # If we want to do something to a file, we have to first create one, aka (initialize one)
        # __init__ means "initialize", the two underscores in pythong mean it's
        # a special function.
        def __init__(self):
                print("initializing a new animal...")

        # One thing that animals do is they eat. It's a "function" of animals.  
        def eat(self):
                print("mmmm... delicious")

# Notice that dogs are a CLASS of animals.
class Dog(Animal):
        # one function of a dog is we have to create a new instance of it
        def __init__(self):
                print("initializing a new dog...")
        # another function is that they bar.
        def bark(self):
                print("woof!")

# This is our main program. Notice it's checking if the name of
# this process is called "main".
if __name__ == "__main__":
        doggo = Dog() # Lets create a new dog, we'll name him doggo
        doggo.eat() # Since dogs are a "class" of animals, they can do everything animals do.
        doggo.bark() # They can also do dog specific stuff.
```